# How to stop event firing in IE (internet explorer) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to stop event firing using JavaScript in the IE. Can anyone tell me how I can do this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you stop an event from firing by preventing its default and returning `false`:

```
foo.onSomeEvent = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```